# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ in someway related to Quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I can't help but notice that they look exactly the same. For example:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ = $\lbrace p + q\sqrt{3}:p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\rbrace$

That seems pretty much exactly an ideal. Only the sqrt takes the ideals place. The operations of this ring seem pretty similar as well

Comment: It is a superficial similarity.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-3)$$ so it is a quotient ring.

Comment: Does that mean that's it is isomorphic to that quotient group? I have never seen that = sign with the tilda above it before. If that's the case, than that would mean they are the exact same thing no? Same as it is for isomorphic groups?

Comment: Firstly, a ring has both addition and multiplication, whereas groups have only one binary operation. Secondly, it takes only one group element to specify a coset $gH$, but it takes two rationals $p,q\in\Bbb Q$ to determine the sum $p+q\sqrt{3}$. Really the only similarity is that you have set-builder notation and a binary operation. You need to stop calling $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ a group too.

Comment: @Prahlad: It's worth pointing out that in that isomorphism, $a+b\sqrt{3}$ corresponds to the coset $a+bx+(x^2-3)$, whereas the OP seems to be saying that the expression $a+b\sqrt{3}$ appears similar to writing $a+I$ where $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: @user121615, that sign means isomorphic; in this case, "isomorphic as rings" or perhaps "isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras."

Comment: @anon, the OP may be referring to the additive group structure.

Comment: Oops. I meant Quotient ring. I shall change it now. Mi bad

Comment: @user121615 As is clear from the comments above, the question is unclear until you specify more precisely what you mean by "seems pretty much exactly an ideal..." What do you mean by that?

Comment: My language has been a little sloppy. I agree. The structure that this thing above seems to create seems A LOT like a quotient ring. I guess that's what I was saying. With what's in the set builder notation seeming pretty similar to a Coset, but not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comment above I said that the similarity is superficial, but perhaps this is not entirely true. Certainly the multiples of $\sqrt 3$ do not form an ideal, but they do form an additive subgroup and a subspace as a $\mathbb Q$ vector space. Hence they form a normal subgroup and one could take the quotient to obtain (a group isomorphic to) $\mathbb Q$. While this is a homomorphism of vector spaces/abelian groups, it is not a ring homomorphism.